# r: can someone explain this dplyr code to me?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Pretty straightforward question. Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% select(hp, disp) %>% 
summarise_all(funs(n=sum(!is.na(.)), mean=mean(.,na.rm=T))) %>% 
gather(variable, value, -gear) %>% 
arrange(gear, sub('_.*', '', variable), sub('.*_', '', variable)) %>%
separate(variable, into = c('var', 'metric'), '_')
```

I understand everything up to the `gather` statement. I'm not familiar with these functions and the help files are not very useful.

Can anyone walk me through this? I'd like to build a function around these commands, but I need to understand how this all works before doing that.

Comment: Have you checked out http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/? There are a lot of resources for this package there as well. Specifically, http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html.

Comment: Uh why is this getting marked down so much?

Comment: You provided a reproducible example, which is great! But, this kind of question has either been asked before or is asking for general information would could be solved through a little searching.

I would spend a little more time reading tutorials on the tidyr package. A google search brings up articles like: http://data.library.virginia.edu/a-tidyr-tutorial/. It's a couple years old, and there may have been some changes, but overall it might be helpful for understanding what tidyr is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gather` moves from "wide" format to long format, `-gear` means don't gather `gear`. `gather` puts the remaining columns into a single `variable` and `value` column.

`arrange` just sorts by gear, the `sub` statements are useless, you could change the `arrange` row to `arrange(gear, variable)`.

`separate` splits the variable column into two using `_` as the delimiter

Comment: How are the sub statement useless ?

Comment: With arrange you can sort by multiple criteria, these can be variables or expressions such as those, they will be used to sort the rows which have the same value for gear and so on

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper for the provided data it sorts the same way whether you split the strings or not.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper regardless it would make more sense to remove that line all together, and put it after `separate` and just use `arrange(gear, var, metric)` and you avoid the RegEx